# Drools rule get from a list object that do not match

Tags: drools

I have a class containing a list. The items in the list have a subtype. I expect that every fact from this class contains a list of items that have the same subtype. I am trying to write a rule that gets all the items coming from the same list and checks whether they have a different subtype. 
The following attempt fails to compile the last condition:

```
public class ListContainer {
    private List<MyType> myTypes;
    //getters-setters-hashcode-equals generated by eclipse
    ...
}



public class MyType{
    private String subType;
    //getters-setters-hashcode-equals generated by eclipse
    ...
}

rule "invalidate inconsistent subtypes"
    when
        $list: ListContainer($myTypes: myTypes)
        $myType1 : MyType() from $myTypes
        $myType2 : MyType() from $myTypes
        not($myType1.subType == $myType2.subType)
    then
        //actions
end
```

The compilation error says it is unable to resolve $myType1.subType 
I suspect that the items that I get with the keyword from are not casted to the original class. However I am not trying to compile this one, I am just looking for the best rule for this problem.

Thank you very much.

---

Here is the version that compiles thanks to laune comment:

```
rule "invalidate inconsistent subtypes"
    when
        $list: ListContainer($myTypes: myTypes)
        $myType : MyType( $subType: subType ) from $myTypes
        exists MyType( subType != $subType ) from $myTypes
    then
        //actions
end
```

Comment: First question - Does MyType have a getSubType() method?

Comment: Second question - Are the objects in the list instances of MyType? You talk about casting, but that DRL doesn't cast anything to MyType. It matches instances of MyType.

Comment: Note, that rule structure will activate for every unequal pair. i.e. For a list [1, 2, 3], I think you would get 6 activations: [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]. Is that what you want?

Comment: Finally ... Do you really need to insert the ListContainer rather than inserting each object as a fact directly? It's easier to write simple, reliable (and importantly, reactive) rules if you don't wrap things.

Comment: @Steve. Question 1: Of course. The comment in the java code means that I do not want to clutter my question with a lot of boilerplate, but it is all there.
Question 2: Yes they are instances of MyTpe. I was wondering what type is actually $myType1 just because subType is not visible.
Question 3: Not a problem, invalid facts are retracted at the first activation.
Question 4: The class names and the example you see are not the real code (same error though). I made a simplified version to be shown in the question. The logic is much more complex and I can't avoid the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The term "subtype" has a specific meaning in Java. It would be better to use another term, e.g. "kind".)

The `not` you have is syntactically incorrect. An eval using Java's logical negation might work, but here's a version that simply established whether a ListContainer has a list with different values of MyType.subType:

```
rule "invalidate inconsistent subtypes"
when
    $list: ListContainer($myTypes: myTypes)
    MyType( $st0: subType ) from $myTypes.get( 0 )
    exists MyType( subType != $st0 ) from $myTypes
then
    System.out.println( "mismatch " + $st0 );
end
```

How many different values there are, and where they are is another matter.

This is your version, corrected:

```
rule "invalidate inconsistent subtypes"
when
    $list: ListContainer($myTypes: myTypes)
    $mt1: MyType( $st1: subType ) from $myTypes
    $mt2: MyType( $st2: subType ) from $myTypes
    eval( ! $st1.equals( $st2 ) )
then
    System.out.println( "mismatch " + $st1 + " " + $st2 );
end
```

But as Steve has correctly commented, this fires twice for each pair of different values within an single ListContainer.

Comment: Thanks laune. exist() was the good tip. I changed a little bit your example for readability, but it compiles now.
BTW. subType shouldn't be the problem because the real code had different naming, but the same error.